# How do I see a design of my databound ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a simple `ListBox` and bound a collection of objects as `ItemsSource`.
The DataTemplate I assigned right now is very simple, but how can I see that template in the designer?

This is my xaml:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And this is how the designer looks:

[image]

And this is how it looks when the data is bound and the app is running:

[image]

How can I get the designer to show a preview of my `DataTemplate`?
I don't need the real data filled in (that happens in runtime), but a preview is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need design time data. You can declare a design-time data context using the [d:DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033600/silverlight-constructor-injection-into-view-model-design-mode/4034057#4034057) property. You can create mock classes that expose mock lists for your the designer to show at design time.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        x:Class="WpfAnswer001.Window1"
        d:DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MockMasterViewModel}"
        Title="Window1" d:DesignWidth="523.5">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="4">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is how you declare the mock view model in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfAnswer001.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAnswer001"
             StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MockMasterViewModel x:Key="MockMasterViewModel"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is how the code for the mock view model looks like:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class MockItemViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class MockMasterViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<MockItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public MockMasterViewModel()
    {
        var item01 = new MockItemViewModel() { Title = "Title 01", Address = "Address 01" };
        var item02 = new MockItemViewModel() { Title = "Title 02", Address = "Address 02" };
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MockItemViewModel>()
        {
            item01, item02
        };
    }
}
```

This is how it looks in Visual Studio:

[image]

Is it worth the effort and coding? That is up to you, but this is how it should be done.

Otherwise, put up with a blank designer and test only at runtime.

This is very useful when you are working a lot with Expression Blend and really need to see how the items look like.

Comment: Does this mean I need to make interfaces for each of my viewmodels? How does this work when I don't have an IoC container?

Comment: I have added more detail on how to do it without an IoC, no need for interfaces.

Comment: I had to close and re-open the solution before Visual Studio picked it up - simply rebuilding didn't help.